# How can I select a range of numbers in Excel that are between certain other numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to record the data from a lever press on an Arduino, and transfer it into Excel. Because the Arduino records data in milliseconds when a button is pressed the data looks like this.

(the picture does not show the whole data string but after the lever is released it goes back to 0;1)

So every time the lever is pushed the first number changes from a "0" to a "1". Because I am only trying to find the number of times the lever is pressed, I need to find how many of these "chunks" of "1"s there are (which will give me how many times the button was pressed then released).

I am trying to find a way to select each group of ones in Excel and translate them into another single cell in another column with the value "1", that way I can then just calculate how many "1"s there are in the other column to find the total presses.

[image: The left number is if the button is being pressed, the right is if a motor is on (1=on, 0=off)]

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
=SUM( --(FREQUENCY( IF(A1:Axxx="1;1",ROW(A1:Axxx)), IF(A1:Axxx="1;1",0,ROW(A1:Axxx)))>0) )
```

where **A1:Axxx** is your range of values.  This creates a frequency array based on the number of contiguous "1;1" in your data. e.g. in the pattern shown in the image below, it would create 0..0,**3**,0..0,**4**,0..0,**1**,0..0,**2**,0..

[image: result]

It then tests if these array values are greater than zero and coerces the results from FALSE/TRUE into 0/1 by using --(formula), so the array now looks like 0..0,**1**,0..0,**1**,0..0,**1**,0..0,**1**,0... Then the SUM adds up the ones and you have your answer in one cell.

Depending on your version of Excel, you might have to enter the formula with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> because it is an array formula.

Comment: @Sophia - is it the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I would make an adjacent column and do something like:

`=IF(AND(LEFT(A1,1)="0", LEFT(A2,1)="1"),1,"")`.

Next I would drag down the formula down, and then sum the resultant range with `=SUM(B1:Bxx)`.